# Holomorphic Polynomial from the Riemann Sphere to Itself

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Helllo friends!

I want to prove that polynomial function $p(z)=z^2-4$ extends to a holomorphic mapping from the Riemann Sphere to itself. I know that four possible combinations of holomorphic charts in domain and codomain must be holomorphic but I do not know how to define these charts to show that the following 4 possible compositions are hol.:

$\psi_1\ o\ f\ o\ \psi_1^{-1}$,

$\psi_2\ o\ f\ o\ \psi_1^{-1}$,

$\psi_1\ o\ f\ o\ \psi_2^{-1}$,

$\psi_2\ o\ f\ o\ \psi_2^{-1}$

I appreciate any help in this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider the extension defined at infinity as $p (\infty) = \infty$. By definition, $p$ is holomorphic at a point $x $ in the sphere iff there exists charts $\phi$ and $\psi$ on neighbourhoods of $x $ and $p (x) $ respectively, such that the function $f = \psi \circ p \circ \phi^{-1}$ is holomorphic (defined in an open set the complex plane) at the point $\phi(x)$. If $z \neq \infty$, the charts are the identity charts (you are in the complex plane). Then, you simply have to check for the infinity point. Taking the chart of infinity at domain and codomain: $\phi = \psi = 1/z$, you can calculate:

$$
f (z) = \psi \circ p \circ \phi^{-1} = \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{z})^2 - 4} = \frac{z}{1 - 4z^2}
$$

This new function is clearly holomorphic at $\phi(\infty) = 0$.

Edit: Denoting the sphere with $S$, open sets with $U = S \setminus \{ \infty \}$ and $V = S \setminus \{ 0\}$ and define the charts $f_1(z) = z$ in $U $ and $f_2 (z) = 1/z$ (this one is the chart of infinity) in V. In the intersection of those you can use either of them.

Comment: No. If you prove it in one, then they all are holomorphic. This is true because all the "coordinate changes" (that is, $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}$) are holomorphic functions in the plane. Then if you know that this holds for one choice of coordinates, you can use this coordinate change to prove this holds for every choice.

Comment: Thanks friend. So, in the proof I can replace $\phi$ and $\psi$ with $f_1$ and $f_2$ respectively right? In case I want to show that the combination $f_2 \circ p \circ f_1^{-1}$ is hol, I should show that it is hol. at $f_1(0)=0$?

Comment: You need to be careful with the neighbourhoods. Only the open set $V$ (with the function $f_2$) can be used in this case, because the open set $U$ does not contain the infinity.

Comment: Since we have to check for infinity point I have to use $V$. How about combination $f_1\circ p\circ f_1^{-1}$ since $U $ does not contain infinity? How can I verify on appropriate open set?

Comment: This is defined only for $z \neq \infty$, and will give you p in the plane